# linux socket client/server program

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Hello my server program is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
int main()
{
    int sfd, cfd;
    int ch='k';
    struct sockaddr_in saddr, caddr;

    sfd= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    saddr.sin_family=AF_INET;           /* Set Address Family to Internet */
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);    /* Any Internet address */
    saddr.sin_port=htons(29008);            /* Set server port to 29008 */
                        /* select any arbitrary Port >1024                */
    bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
    listen(sfd, 1);
    while(1) {
            printf("Server waiting...");
            cfd=accept(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)NULL, NULL);
            if(read(cfd, &ch, 1)<0) perror("read");
            ch++;
            if(write(cfd, &ch, 1)<0) perror("write");
            close(cfd);
    }
}
```

so i got a simple server program and i also got a client program. The problem i have is that when i run both at the same machine on different terminals the client output works fine. The server although doesnt print the waiting line and also it stacks making me unable to use terminal. Whats the problem ?

Comment: The output mechanism you are using is *line buffered* meaning output will generally not be generated until you send a newline or call fflush(stdout).  Additionally, the way you are opening socket can prevent it from being re-used immediately if not shutdown cleanly, so subsequent invocations of your program may fail to open it, something you might not see as you have little error reporting.

Comment: Yeah. It's also kind of "fork"-ed up not to split accept functions, and a generally good idea to make some way to exit that server loop. Eventually every server wants to come down, and you're going to make some server admin very nervous if the only way he can install a new blade is by pressing ctrl-c on the server programs.

Comment: Does your client establish a fresh `connect()`ion for each character it sends?

Comment: yeah fflush( stdout ) was the problem. Btw what you mean is kind of forked up? And whats a better way of oppening a socket? Thanks for your replies!

Comment: I was making a joke about forking connections from different clients so that they can run under different processes.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment points out, you need send a new line or `fflush(stdout)` to make the server print what you want, or disable buffering entirely before operating on `stdout`: `setbuf(stdout, NULL)`, which is not necessary. By default, `stdout` is line buffered, `stderr` is none buffered. And note that Microsoft runtime libraries do not support line buffering, so if you implement this program with Winsock, it will print immediately.
Before `bind()`, you can set the `SO_REUSEADDR` option so that when your program exits uncleanly(in the code above, you didn't close the listening socket `sfd` explicitly, though the OS will clean up upon termination, but it's a good practice to do so), the port which may remain in TIME_WAIT state can be re-used immediately.

```
int yes = 1;
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int))
```

If you want to use the current terminal after you run the program, add a `&` after your command, so the program will run in the background.